# How to separate database on 2 different table html

Tags: python, flask

i have database for example

| id | account_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 127 | 2022-04-25 |
| 2 | 128 | 2022-04-25 |
| 3 | 127 | 2022-04-24 |
| 4 | 128 | 2022-04-24 |

And i need separate this on 2 different tables:

| account_id | date header |
| --- | --- |
| 127 | 2022-04-25 |
| 127 | 2022-04-24 |

and the same with 128

That's my code for 1 table and i don't know how to separate

```
@bp.route('/')
def main():
    wcms = Wcm.query.order_by(Wcm.date.desc()).all()
    return render_template('table.html', wcms=wcms)
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark wcm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>WCM account ID</th>
                <th>Number of standard tags</th>
                <th>Number of extended tags</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for wcm in wcms %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ wcm.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.account_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.nbm_stardart_tags }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.nbm_custom_tags }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following code to work we need to sort the data by the grouping value first. Since you want to seperate account IDs, I chose ASC.

```
wcms = Wcm.query.order_by(Wcm.account_id.asc(), Wcm.date.desc()).all()
```

The lambda returns the account ID to collect all entries into one list. [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) returns a `list` of `tuples`, the `list()` call is needed to evaluate the lazy iterator creating the group. The outer list comprehensions creates a list of those grouped Wcm lists.

```
wcms_by_account = [
    list(wcm_group) 
    for acc_id, wcm_group 
    in groupby(wcms, lambda x: x.account_id
]
```

List strucure:

```
[
    [
        Wcm(account_id=127, date=2022-04-25, ...),
        Wcm(account_id=127, date=2022-04-24, ...),
    ],
    [
        Wcm(account_id=128, date=2022-04-25, ...),
        Wcm(account_id=128, date=2022-04-24, ...),
    ],
    ...
]
```

Then change your Web Template to handle a list of lists, creating a new table for each inner list.

```
{% for wcms in wcms_by_account %}
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark wcm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>WCM account ID</th>
                <th>Number of standard tags</th>
                <th>Number of extended tags</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for wcm in wcms %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ wcm.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.account_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.nbm_stardart_tags }}</td>
                    <td>{{ wcm.nbm_custom_tags }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```